# How to test a microservice by mocking the dependencies?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing, automated-tests

I've a RESTFul microservice written in Grails. This microservice has it's own DB. It also depends on two other microservices.

A typical workflow of the service is:

1. Receives a GET request from a client e.g. browser
2. Calls another microservice throw http to get some information
3. Queries it's own DB to get some data
4. Send a response to the client

I want to write automated tests for this service. Whenever I'll run the test, it'll do the following:

- Mock the external microservices
- Create a database and populate it with test data
- Run the application and configure it to use the mock services and DB
- Run the test cases by sending http requests and matching responses

Here are my questions:

- What type of test is this?
- What are some good frameworks or tools to write this type of test?

I've a very little knowledge on testing so may be I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: Seems to be a hybrid of Unit and Integration tests. In a unit test, everything outside the method being tested should be controlled/mocked (microservices and DB).As for tools/framework, I tend towards a combination of Spock Specifications and Groovy tools (mockFor and metaClassing)

Comment: As a starting point have you checked the chapter regarding testing in documentation? http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is that your service not know about HTTP requests.  It should be a provider to a higher level layer like https://jersey.java.net that can make requests and map the POJO's your service class returns into JSON or whatever to return in HTTP responses.

Your method for #4, "Send a response to the client" should use those external dependencies to gather information and then make a decision.

Some cases to cover:
If the other micro service can return A, B, or C and the DB can return D, E, or F, then you have 9 scenarios to test.  Use mocks to provide all those varieties of data and then make assertions about the result.  If there are many more possibilities, then consider adding extra methods for information-gathetering and testing them on their own.